# Is it possible to connect to a remote server from another remote server using Robot framework

Tags: linux, testing, automation, robotframework

I am currently using ***SSHLibrary*** for connecting to a remote server using robot framework for my testing purpose . But I need to establish connection to a 2nd server (for running some commands and obtain some results),to which direct connection from my laptop is not possible . Only way to connect to this 2nd server is , login to the server 1 then ssh .

So is there any way I can achieve this using robot framework . Any other libraries or keywords available ?

I tried searching but could not succeed . Any help is very much appreciated as I am stuck in this for long time now .

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there is no direct library for this, moreover i believe we don't need any separate library for this.

To achieve this you can create a .sh file on your laptop which would contain commands to connect to 3rd machine and execute required commands. like:

```
sshpass -p <password> ssh <user>@<ip_of_3rdServer> 'command/commands here'
```

Through the robotframework you just have copy this .sh file to the "proxy machine"(2nd machine) and then run it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion . Even I thought of the way you mentioned above . But I could be having many conditions to check for the command results and act accordingly . So I  was looking to see if there is any way we can get the connection to the 2nd server and stay there  ,once we establish connection with the first server using **Open Connection** keyword from the RIDE in my laptop. So if there is no Library available for this then I think this is the way to check then . Also will check if any other suggestions are posting here .

Comment: Well, when you say you want to use "Open Connection" keyword. You could also try  Laptop --> Server1 --> Server2 ; Robot --> Robot --> Shell, or OpenConnection --> OpenConnection --> Execute Commands. I mean whatever you are planning to do with OpenConnection if it was available to connect to 3rd server, you can write the same robot code and run it from Server1. I will be as good as connecting from laptop --> Server2.

Comment: Correct.Problem is I don't have a Robot installation in my Servers . It is installed only in my laptop and I would be running the test cases from my laptop.